# stop alt+f4 working after install window7 -64bit

Tags: windows-7

I have a Dell Inspirion N5010 and before installing Windows 7 64bit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> was working normally, but after reinstalling Windows 7, the function keys <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F12</kbd> are working without the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> stopped working.

Advance me thankss

Comment: Please edit your question, it is rather hard to understand what you mean.

Comment: Please be more precise on what you expect to happen and what really happens.

Answer (score 0):

Is your problem that your function keys' functionality is reversed, i.e. hitting fn+f1 does what f1 is supposed to, and vice versa? If so, you should be able to fix that by changing the setting in bios.